# Problema al generar una ruta con Path.Combine

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Tengo el siguiente problema, que me tiene un poco de cabeza... :( estoy formateando 3 string para formar una ruta con Path.Combine (C# y WPF) en el primer string tiene su origen en un TextBox (este es el problemático), los otros dos los obtengo de un objeto.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
string origen;
string destino;

List<Archivos> listaArchivosDescarga = DataTableToObjeto.ConvertirDataTableEnListaObjetos<Archivos>(archivos.BuscarPorVersion(1));

foreach(Archivos archivo in listaArchivosDescarga)
{
     origen = Path.Combine(archivo.RutaServidor, archivo.NombreArchivoVirtual);
     destino = Path.Combine(TbxRutaDestinoCliente.Text, archivo.Ruta, archivo.NombreArchivoFisico);

     File.Copy(origen, destino, true);
}
```

El problema es que el segundo Combine que me genera el destino del archivo, pasa totalmente del contenido de TextBox y a la hora de formatear la ruta, solo "ve" las dos ultimas variables de esta linea (archivo.Ruta y archivo.NombreArchivoFisico)

Dentro del `TextBox` tengo por ejemplo: `"C:\pruebas"`, en la variable `archivo.Ruta`, tengo `"\BIN\"` y en `archivo.NombreArchivoFisico`: `"cmdline.cmd"`, el resultado del `Combine` es: `"\BIN\cmdline.cmd"`.

Por favor, alguien me puede echar un cable.

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias agregar un ejemplo? porque hay versiones de string que invalidan el path que tratas de construir...

Comment: Javi, muestra que valores estas pasando y cual es el resultado que `Path.Combine` te retorna para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Einer Dentro del TextBox tengo por ejemplo: "C:\pruebas", en la variable archivo.Ruta, tengo "\BIN\" y en archivo.NombreArchivoFisico: "cmdline.cmd", el resultado del Combine es: "\BIN\cmdline.cmd". Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: El problema está en el `\BIN\ ` . Al tener ya un comienzo de ruta, "sobreescribe" lo anterior. Si pruebas con `BIN\ `, verás que te funciona bien

Comment: Perfecto @Pikoh Respuesta de 10. Un millón de gracias!!

Comment: Podras poner toda la info que esta en comentarios en la pregunta??? usa el boton [edit] y dejala ordenada por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segun la documentacion de [`System.IO.Path.Combin`e](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Si una de las rutas especificadas es una cadena de longitud cero, este
>   método devuelve la otra ruta. S**i `path2` contiene una ruta absoluta,
>   este método devuelve `path2`**.

Esto lo que significa que al agregar `\` delante del path 2 `\BIN\`, esta es interpretada como path absoluta.

Intenta eliminado el backslash en el path2, osea, eliminar el backslash al inicio. En vez de `\BIN\`, seria `BIN\`:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\pruebas", @"\BIN\", "cmd.exe") // "\\bin\\cmd.exe"
System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\pruebas", @"BIN\", "cmd.exe") // "C:\\pruebas\\bin\\cmd.exe"
```

Comment: Por favor aclarenme un detalle: ¿Si hay una respuesta suficientemente buena en los comentarios, tiene sentido reescribirla, sin hacerle referencia?

Comment: quevedo, mientras @Pikoh escribia ese comentario ya yo estaba escribiendo esta respuesta por lo que no sabia que se habia escrito algo igual. Incluso ya yo sabia cual era el error solo que espera por el OP para confirmar lo que el estaba pasando.

Comment: @quevedo si alguien pone una respuesta en los comentarios, otra persona puede usar ese comentario como idea para elaborar una respuesta. No es obligatorio referenciar ese comentario pero si se considera un buen gesto ponerlo. Y realmente no sabemos si Einer usó el comentario de Pikoh o si detectó el fallo de igual manera. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones. Pregunté porque en alguna pregunta que quise responder encontré que sólo había reorganizado lo que había en comentarios que no había leído. Y, obviamente borré mi respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Segun aclaras en tus comentarios, una de las partes, concretamente `archivo.Ruta` es `\BIN\`. El problema es que es una ruta absoluta, por lo que lo anterior se descarta.

La solución es sencilla. Si esa propiedad siempre comienza con backslash,puedes hacer un `Substring`:

```
destino = Path.Combine(TbxRutaDestinoCliente.Text, archivo.Ruta.Substring(1), archivo.NombreArchivoFisico");
```

Si no estas seguro, siempre puedes reemplazar todos los backslashes de esa propiedad:

```
destino = Path.Combine(TbxRutaDestinoCliente.Text, archivo.Ruta.Replace("\\", ""), archivo.NombreArchivoFisico");
```

Comment: No es justo. Ya yo la habia respondido TT.TT ... Aun asi +1.

Comment: Un millón (+1 por ser tan rápido!) de gracias Pikoh. Problema resuelto y super detallada la respuesta!

Comment: Lo que escribi arriba  fue solo una broma. No pretendia obtener la aceptacion del OP por haber contestado primero. Al final, esto no es una competencia.

Comment: Perdon no, pero yo lo dije antes que uds dos, cuando le dije que habia versiones de combine que funcionaban distinto dependiendo las rutas :p

Comment: Pikoh, se me olvido poner la palabra 'no' en la oración y salio como si dijese que es una compentencia haha. Perdona, el universo esta en mi contra hoy.